# How I can generate a matrix from a set of terms?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I want to build a matrix, from the following set $S = \{a b , a c\}$

```
  S = {a b , a c}
```

where the terms of S represent the raw of the matrix `m` , and the element in S represent the column of the matrix `m` , then we get

Column of m such that `c1={a,a},c2={b,0} and c3={0,c}`

raw of m such that `r1={a,b,0} and r2={a,0,c}`

building `m` from columns `m={c1,c2,c3}`
or building `m` from raw  `m={r1,r2}`,
then we get

```
m={{a, b, 0}, {a, 0, c}}
```

> $m=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}  a & b & 0 \\  a & 0 & c \\ \end{array}
>  \right)$

Is this possible in practice?

In general, is this possible regardless of the terms of set?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @glS Not duplicate. The idea varies in matrix construction depending on the set.

Comment: I read the question several times but I do not get it. Maybe you mix up MATLAB's and Mathematicas notations for matrices? Have you ever read about `Transpose`? Do you know that `a b` means $a \cdot b$ in Mathematica?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for trying to help me. Answer by @Mr.Wizard♦

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### New method

Leveraging [`CoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientRules.html).

```
S = {a b, a c};

var = Variables[S];

var # & /@ CoefficientRules[S][[All, 1, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 0}, {a, 0, c}}
> ```

---

#### Old Method

```
S = {a b, a c};

rls = MapIndexed[# -> #2.{1} -> # &, Variables[S]];

m = PadRight[SparseArray /@ (List @@@ S /. rls)]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 0}, {a, 0, c}}
> ```

---

Automation of Carl Woll's method:

```
PowerExpand @ Log[S /. Thread[# -> Exp@DiagonalMatrix@#]] & @ Variables[S]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 0}, {a, 0, c}}
> ```

Comment: Try `CoefficientRules[S][[All, 1, 1]].DiagonalMatrix[var]`.

Comment: @J.M. I actually considered that but you know how much I like brevity and `var # & /@` was shorter.

Comment: Thank you so much . This exact solution.

Answer (score 5):

One idea:

```
S = {a b, a c};

PowerExpand @ Log[S /. {a -> Exp[{a, 0, 0}], b -> Exp[{0, b, 0}], c -> Exp[{0, 0, c}]}]
```

> {{a, b, 0}, {a, 0, c}}

Comment: Thank you so much. But if $ S=\{a,abc,ade,ad,ae\} $This will require many inputs. When the terms of s are increased are getting harder. – Emad kareem

Answer (score 1):

```
rule = Thread[Variables[S] -> DiagonalMatrix[Variables[S]]];
Block[{Times = Plus}, S /. rule]
```

> {{a,b,0},{a,0,c}}